# Why is my TStrings object being destroyed before my destructor has a chance to run?

Tags: delphi

I have a an object that extends from TFrame. This contains a TCombobox.

I want to make sure i free any associated objects when my frame is destroyed. However when my destructor gets run i can access the combobox, but it's items have been wiped out.

What would do this? How can i access the items in the destructor?

my destructor looks like this;

```
destructor TfraImportAttachments.Destroy;
begin

  MessageDlg(IntToStr(cboCategory.Items.count), mtInformation, [mbOK], 0);
  FreeObjects(cboCategory.Items);

  inherited;
end;
```

Comment: My main form owns the frame, when the OnDestroy gets called for the main form the items exists, but then my destructor is fired and they are gone. So something must be happening inbetween.

Comment: IRC, with frames there is no exact timing of creation and destruction - maybe that's the issue.

Comment: A `DestroyHandle` may have reached the combobox before the destructor. Then the Items are gone because they are not saved to the `TCustomComboBox.FSavedItems` list in `TCustomComboBox.DestroyWnd`. I always tell my fellow developers to not use a combobox for controlling the object lifetime.

Comment: @iamjosy, ok maybe, but how do i work with that? The combobox still exists, only it's items are gone. That just seems weird. How i am supposed to clean up objects that i've created if not in the destructor?

Comment: @Andreas Hausladen. You are probably right. Annoying though when i have followed an artical on about.com telling me how to attach objects to a TString list. It's a convenient way to associate objects with items in a combobox. How would you do it?

Comment: @sryner: The combobox Delphi object still exists, but the actual control (the one that is accessed through the window handle) is gone. By accessing `ComboBox.Items` the VCL recreates the actual control so it can retrieve the items, but that new control doesn't have any items.      I would put the items into the combobox and a TObjectList/TList/TList<TObject> depending on what you want to do with them. So the ownership is in the "code" list while the items are still referenced in the combobox.

Comment: @Andreas Hausladen Thank you this is very comprehensive answer and very usefull. How can i mark it as the accepted answer?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A `DestroyHandle` may have reached the combobox before the destructor. Then the Items are gone because they are not saved to the `TCustomComboBox.FSavedItems` list in `TCustomComboBox.DestroyWnd`.

The combobox Delphi object still exists, but the actual control (the one that is accessed through the window handle) is gone. By accessing ComboBox.Items the VCL recreates the actual control so it can retrieve the items, but that new control doesn't have any items, so `Items.Count` returns 0.

A solution would be to put the items into the combobox and a `TObjectList`, `TList` or `TList<TObject>` depending on what you want to do with them. So the ownership is in the "code" list while the items are still referenced in the combobox.